# find files with extended attributes

Tags: find, xattr

Can I use `find` to find all files which have extended attributes set? Let's say, I want to find all files with `+i`, immutable attribute in `/foo` and its subfolders.

I could not find any, mention of extended attributes in `man find`.

Is there any other way to find all files with attributes

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: @DopeGhoti, I was about to provide the link to Gille's answer. It uses `find` method. The link to Gille's answer is [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134027/47538).

Comment: BSD `find` (the same that comes with Mac OS) has both `-xattr` and `-xattrname` options to deal with extended attributes. To find files that have extended attributes set you can just use something like `find . -xattr -exec xattr -v {} \;`. Use `-xattrname` to search for specific attributes.

Comment: To delete an attribute by name for example: `find ~/some-path/ -xattrname com.apple.FinderInfo -exec xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo {} \;`

Comment: @ClaudioFloreani Do you have a source for that? I can't find `-xattr` in any manpage from MacOS, FreeBSD or OpenBSD.

Comment: there is now a fresh utility that wraps find and supports this for any POSIX compliant OS, you can find it at https://github.com/Cbhihe/findxattr

Comment: Immutability is a file attribute (Linux) or file flag (BSDs), not necessarily an extended attribute. Some systems store file attributes as extended attributes but extended attributes are generic key/value stores. My rawhide (rh) program can search for both. To find immutable files do `rh / immutable`. To find files with a particular extended attribute (name or value) do `rh / '"*pattern*".ea'`. It's at https://github.com/raforg/rawhide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find itself doesn't support extended atttribute but you can use such as:

```
find ~/ -type f  -iname "*" -exec lsattr {} + | grep  -v -- '-------------'
```

Comment: This would be very slow as it runs `lsattr` for **every single file**, and there is no need to match `*` - **use this instead**: `find /foo -type f -print0 | xargs -0 lsattr | grep -v -- '-------------'`

Comment: Actually looking at the other answer (this one is a duplicate) `lsattr` supports the `-R` switch (recursive).